# IGMP Snooping limitations and when do you start to use PIM?

Tags: networking, routing, multicast, cisco-catalyst, igmp

At a head end I've just inherited, all our multicast streams run on cisco switches with IGMP snooping enabled. Because all these streams are to be kept local and isolated we've never really looked into implementing routing protocols.

However, I want to start doing multicast out of our contribution encoders (we're also an ISP so we control the WAN links between the encoders and the head end) so I really have 2 questions:

1. For my first (isolated/local) network: When will IGMP snooping stop being enough and under which circumstances should I consider routing?
2. For streams over my WAN links: Is there a way to force my core (OSPF enabled) routers to send a specific multicast address only to some specific destinations?